# How to implement Google Play-like scores

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to implement something like that (Google Play scores):

[image]

Where the user can click in a concrete star to indicate the score. The point is that I don't know what is the best approach for this, maybe place the 5 stars in a row, with an onClick in every imageView? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [RatingBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html) which implements selectable star ratings for you.